# Getting class name of instance and using it to create new instances in JS

Tags: javascript, class, instance, instanceof

I have many instances of different classes, I want to select any of them randomly (say `inst1`) and create a new instance of the class of selected instance (say `cls1`).
This is how I'm implementing it:

```
// getting class name of selected instance (say inst1), i.e. clsName is cls1
let clsName = inst1.constructor.name;

// use the class name obtained above to create new instance
let newInst = new clsName();
```

But it gives me error saying;
"***Uncaught TypeError: clsName is not a constructor at HTMLDocument.***"

Is there a way to get around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`claName` is a string, not a function. The constructor function is `inst1.constructor`, call that.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    console.log("constructing a Test");
  }
}

inst1 = new Test();
cls = inst1.constructor;
inst2 = new cls;
```